# Pyinstaller executable doesn't work/run. What might be the problem?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

good afternoon. I know that this is a question frequently made here, but among all the questions i've searched I didnt find some answer to help me with my problem.
I'm trying to create a simple executable using the Pyinstaller.
The code is this one:

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
ser = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

def led_on():
    ser.write(str.encode('1'))
def led_off():
    ser.write(str.encode('0'))

def main():
    window = Tk()
    btn  = Button(window, text = "ON", command = led_on)
    btn1 = Button(window, text = "OFF", command = led_off)
    btn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code is running perfectly.
I then created the executable using the cmd prompt. Once inside the file where the py file is in, i enter the following code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile file_name.py
```

I then go to the "dist" directory and try to run the executable. Nothing happens. I also tried to run it from the cmd prompt. Also nothing happens.
I could really use some help here.
Thank you

Comment: I don't think cmd shows nothing. It should show error. It must be showing up fast. So try capturing it and updating the Q with it.

Comment: Try `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=serial file_name.py`

Comment: Cool Cloud unfortunatly i wasn't able to retreive the erros. acw1668 I created the exe file using your command, but when i try to run it, again nothing happens. But during the exe file creation a warning txt file is created indicating missing modules. I'm now trying to figure out what to do now. Three of these missing modules are top-level:                       
missing module named fcntl - imported by serial.serialposix (top-level)
missing module named 'System.IO' - imported by serial.serialcli (top-level)
missing module named System - imported by serial.serialcli (top-level)